# Why this code source in fiddle does not work on my local

Tags: javascript, html

Did i miss something here in the html/js page ? the code is running good in JSFIDDLE but not in my desk !!!!

> > > this is the working fiddle  : http://jsfiddle.net/WNDQJ/1/result/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addRow").click(function () {
            $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>row</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr>");
        });
      });
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>row</td>
        <td>
          <input type='text'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row</td>
        <td>
          <input type='text'>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="addRow" value="add" />
  </body>
</html>
```

any idea please ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didnt included jquery. please visit http://jquery.org for more info

Comment: what is your error? could you check console?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">

  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#addRow").click(function () {
        $("#myTable").append("<tr><td>row</td><td><input type='text'></td></tr>");
    });
});
</script>
```

Have you loaded the jQuery library into your webpage prior to using $(document).ready()?

Comment: If he created new jsfiddle himself, he might include jquery. It doesnt in js fiddle work without jquery

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone, finally by adding ;: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"> it works. thank you JONAS/IMUDIN/DYALL

Comment: Good! you have to accept this answer for further usage :)